# Running asynchronous queries parallelly (IAsyncEnumerable)

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, async-await, parallel-processing

The code below connects to a database and queries articleinfo and then, their count stored in a chaotic storage. I would like to run these queries parallelly. Now the `QueryItems` runs first, because I await that foreach first. Only after that can `QueryCount` run.

My question is: **How can I run thes async queries parallelly?**

```
internal async void InitializeItems()
{
    await foreach (Item i in this.QueryItems())
    {
        this.items.Add(i);
        this.view.ComboBoxArticle.Items.Add(i.ArticleNumber);
    }

    await foreach (ValueTuple<int, string> t in this.QueryCount())
        this.items.Where(it => it.ArticleNumber.Equals(t.Item2))
            .FirstOrDefault().Count = t.Item1;
}

private async IAsyncEnumerable<Item> QueryItems()
{
    using (OdbcConnection conItems = new OdbcConnection(
        Properties.Settings.Default.PaConnString))
    using (OdbcCommand cmdItems = new OdbcCommand())
    {
        cmdItems.Connection = conItems;
        cmdItems.CommandText = @"SELECT PUB.S_Artikel.Artikel AS ArticleNumber, 
        PUB.S_ArtikelSpr.Bezeichnung AS ArticleName, 
        PUB.S_ArtKtoGr.KontenGruppe AS CapacityGroup, 
        PUB.S_ArtKtoGr.Verbrauchskonto AS CostCenter, 
        PUB.S_KontoSpr.Bezeichnung AS CostName, 
        PUB.S_MengenEinheitSpr.Bezeichnung AS Unit
    FROM PUB.S_Artikel 
        INNER JOIN PUB.S_ArtikelSpr 
            ON PUB.S_Artikel.Artikel = PUB.S_ArtikelSpr.Artikel 
                AND PUB.S_ArtikelSpr.Sprache = 'H' 
        INNER JOIN PUB.SBM_ValueFlowGroup 
            ON PUB.S_Artikel.SBM_ValueFlowGroup_Obj
                = PUB.SBM_ValueFlowGroup.SBM_ValueFlowGroup_Obj 
        INNER JOIN PUB.S_ArtKtoGr 
            ON PUB.SBM_ValueFlowGroup.S_ArtKtoGr_Obj = PUB.S_ArtKtoGr.S_ArtKtoGr_Obj
        INNER JOIN PUB.S_KontoSpr 
            ON PUB.S_ArtKtoGr.Verbrauchskonto = PUB.S_KontoSpr.Konto
                AND PUB.S_KontoSpr.Sprache = 'H'
        INNER JOIN PUB.S_MengenEinheitSpr 
            ON PUB.S_Artikel.LagerME = PUB.S_MengenEinheitSpr.MengenEinheit 
                AND PUB.S_MengenEinheitSpr.Sprache = 'H' " +
    "WHERE PUB.S_Artikel.Firma = '100' " + "AND PUB.S_Artikel.archiviert = 0 " +
    "ORDER BY PUB.S_Artikel.Artikel";

        conItems.Open();
        if (!conItems.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
            throw new Exception(
                "Nem sikerült a cikkinformációk lekérdezése (a PA szerverről).");

        using (DbDataReader readerItems = await Task.Run(
            () => cmdItems.ExecuteReader()))
        {
            while (await Task.Run(() => readerItems.ReadAsync()))
            {
                yield return new Item
                    (
                        readerItems.GetString(0),
                        readerItems.GetString(1),
                        readerItems.GetString(2),
                        readerItems.GetString(3),
                        readerItems.GetString(4),
                        readerItems.GetString(5)
                    );
            }
            await Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("ITEMS END"));
        }
    }
}

private async IAsyncEnumerable<ValueTuple<int, string>> QueryCount()
{
    using (OdbcConnection conCount = new OdbcConnection(
        Properties.Settings.Default.PaConnString))
    using (OdbcCommand cmdCount = new OdbcCommand())
    {
        cmdCount.Connection = conCount;
        cmdCount.CommandText = @"SELECT SUM(PUB.MP_ArtPlatz.Bestand),
            PUB.MP_ArtPlatz.Artikel AS ArticleNumber
        FROM PUB.MP_ArtPlatz
        GROUP BY PUB.MP_ArtPlatz.Artikel";

        conCount.Open();
        if (!conCount.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
            throw new Exception("Nem skerült a ProAlpha adatbázisához"
                + " kapcsolódni a darabszám lekérdezése érdekében.");

        using (DbDataReader readerCount = await Task.Run(
            () => cmdCount.ExecuteReaderAsync()))
            while (await Task.Run(() => readerCount.ReadAsync()))
            {
                //{
                //    Item i = this.items.Where(
                //        it => it.ArticleNumber.Equals(artNum)).FirstOrDefault();
                //    i.Count = count;
                //}
                yield return new ValueTuple<int, string>(
                    readerCount.GetInt32(0), readerCount.GetString(1));
            }
    }
}
```

In the UserControl's load method I call them like this:

```
private void MaterialRequestUC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //...
        this.presenter.InitializeItems();
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(
        "Hiba: " + ex.Message, "Hiba", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
}
```

Comment: *"caotic storage"* Hi Ferenc. What do you mean by this?

Comment: The SQL Server is multithreaded and all queries are automatically run in parallel depending on the number of cores in the machine.

Comment: A chaotic storage means that doesn't every item has a fixed position (row, column and floor) in a storage. But, one type of item can be at multiple positions at a time. However, these datas can be retrived from the database unambiguously. And I have to handle all of the items (QueryItems()) and need the count of each in the storage (QueryCount).
But in my software, all of the breakpoints I have placed proved that first, the items are queried and that comobobox is filled. And the sum of the items are only queried after the first foreach is done.

Comment: What is the type of the `this.items` field?

Comment: The whole project is big to copy here... It's from type Item (own type) for each record of the result set of QueryItems. Has several datamembers, as you can see it in the code.

Comment: Is it a `List<Item>`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If what you mean is that you want the querycount to work in parallel, then do `Task.Run` instead of `await`.

```
internal async void InitializeItems()
{
    await foreach (Item i in this.QueryItems())
    {
        this.items.Add(i);
        this.view.ComboBoxArticle.Items.Add(i.ArticleNumber);
    }

    Task.Run(async () => await foreach (ValueTuple<int, string> t in this.QueryCount())
        this.items.Where(it => it.ArticleNumber.Equals(t.Item2))
            .FirstOrDefault().Count = t.Item1);
}
```